# Rust Compiler picking collection::string instead of std::string

Tags: string, rust

I'm having some trouble figuring out why rustc is assuming I am wanting to use `collection::string::String` instead of `std::string::String`.

I've no direct use statements pulling it in, and have specific use statement declaring

This is a simplified version of my crate root:

```
extern crate serialize;
extern crate collections;

use std::str;
use std::string::String;
use std::io::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{Listener, Acceptor};
use self::serialize::json;
use self::serialize::json::Json;
use self::collections::tree_map::TreeMap;

use self::socket::Socket;
use self::socket::event::Event;
use self::socket::action::Action;
use self::socket::message::{Message, Text, Binary};
use self::server::Server;
use self::httpheader::{RequestHeader, ReturnHeader};
use self::socketmessenger::SocketMessenger;

pub mod socket;
pub mod server;
mod httpheader;
mod socketmessenger;
```

This is the top of my mod throwing the error:

```
extern crate "rust-crypto" as rust_crypto;

use self::rust_crypto::digest::Digest;
use self::rust_crypto::sha1::Sha1;
use super::serialize::base64::{ToBase64, STANDARD};
use super::std::string::String;

pub struct RequestHeader {
    pub upgrade: String,
    pub connection: String,
    pub host: String,
    pub origin: String,
    pub pragma: String,
    pub cache_control: String,
    pub sec_websocket_key: String,
    pub sec_websocket_version: String,
    pub sec_websocket_extensions: String,
    pub user_agent: String
}
```

The compiler is giving me:

```
src/httpheader/mod.rs:156:25: 156:42 error: type `collections::string::String` does not implement any method in scope named `push_bytes`
src/httpheader/mod.rs:156             stringified.push_bytes(bytes);
```

When I try and push bytes onto the String like so:

```
unsafe {
    let bytes = self.sec_websocket_accept.as_bytes();
    stringified.push_bytes(bytes);
}
```

I would assume that my `String` there is from `std::string::String`, not `collections::string::String` because I've not specified anywhere that I would like to use the `String` from the collections crate.

Can anyone advise on why I am seeing this behavior?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std` is mostly just the parts of the other crates pulled together with `pub use`—`std::string` *is* `collections::string`.

Answer (score 5):

Rust has a notion of `pub use`, which reexports an identifier from a module. For example, here:

```
pub mod a {
    pub use b::Struct;
}

pub mod b {
    pub struct Struct;
}
```

You can use `Struct` both from `a` and from `b`:

```
use a::Struct;
// or
use b::Struct;
```

This mechanism is used a lot in Rust standard libraries. In particular, a big chunk of `std` functionality is in fact defined in other crates and reexported by `std` for convenience. `String`, for example, is defined in `collections` crate, however, it is reexported by `std::string` module and, more importantly, it is also reexported by `std::prelude`, whose contents are automatically imported in all regular modules. This means that `collections::string::String`, which is also `std::string::String`, can be accessed just as `String`, so you don't need to import it explicitly.

Your problem, however, is not importing. `String` just [does not contain](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) `push_bytes()` (why did you think it does, in the first place?). This is for a reason. `String` is guaranteed to be a proper UTF-8 sequence, so pushing arbitrary bytes to it is unsafe - you could easily push a sequence of bytes which are invalid UTF-8, breaking the guarantee.

If you need to work with bytes, you should use [`Vec<u8>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), which is a generic growable bytes buffer. When you are finished pushing new bytes to it and if you are sure that these bytes represent valid UTF-8, you can use [`String::from_utf8()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) static method (or `from_utf8_lossy()`, or `from_utf16()`/`from_utf16_lossy()` if your input is UTF-16) to convert `Vec<u8>` into `String` efficiently.

Comment: Why did I think it did?  Well, `String` used to contain that unsafe function, until a few weeks ago I guess, when my code started breaking.  Then, I checked docs again, and `std::string::String` contained the function, but `collections::string::String` did not.  Was thinking the compiler was choosing the wrong String.  Now, looking at `std::string::String` again, I probably hit the old docs hosted by MIT and got confused.

Comment: Indeed, it was removed [almost a month ago](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/9d5d97b55d6487ee23b805bc1acbaa0669b82116#diff-74da6d3cb2e346055e7e2b5ead7463fb). Never knew there was such a method. (Sorry if my remark seemed mean to you, I honestly didn't mean any offense!)